# Device Support Removed- Google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I got error `notification` when trying to upload/update new APK to Google Play Console.
It's like my newer `APK` version is supporting fewer Device than my old `APK`. I added two things in the manifest file.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

How I solve this?

[image: Device Support Removed]

Comment: When you add these two lines, you disable devices that do not have a camera and do not have auto focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devices without camera and auto-focus gets filtered out because you added the `uses-feature`. Some Android devices might not have a camera, or no support for auto-focus.

If the camera isn't required for your app, and you just added it as an additional option. You can use `android:required="false"` to the `uses-feature`.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"  android:required="false"/>
```

Make sure that you only display the camera-option when the device has got an actual camera. Otherwise it could lead to a crash on devices without a camera.

You can check if the device has a camera by using this code:

```
/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add these two lines, you disable devices that do not have a camera and do not have auto focus.
The only solution to this is to stop adding.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is because

1) Google Play uses the `<uses-feature>` elements declared in your app manifest to filter your app from devices that do not meet its hardware and software feature requirements.

2) The older devices that were previously supported, will no longer be able to download the latest version of your app from Google Play Store

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down further on the Play Store Review page, you should see a breakdown of the reasons the app is no longer supported, with info on which devices, and how many of your current installs, are affected.

(In our case this was almost exclusively because of upgrading the SDK version.)

[image]